# c - standard file descriptor - open if missing

Tags: c, git, stdio

I saw following function in *setup.c* of git source code.

**Code:**

```
/* if any standard file descriptor is missing open it to /dev/null */
void sanitize_stdfds(void)
{
        int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR, 0); 
        while (fd != -1 && fd < 2)
                fd = dup(fd);
        if (fd == -1) 
                die_errno("open /dev/null or dup failed");
        if (fd > 2)
                close(fd);
}
```

It try to open stdio file descriptors (0/1/2) to /dev/null, if they are missing.

**My question is:**

In `while (fd != -1 && fd < 2)` , why use **2**, but not **3**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if `fd == 2` you have opened file descriptors 0,1,2 and there is nothing more to do. You only needed to open those 3 descriptors for stdin, stdout and stderr.

If you put there 3, the loop would open file descriptors 0,1,2,3. Then the line `if (fd > 2) close(fd);` would close the descriptor 3. So it will work in both cases, but the original solution is better.

Comment: if you put there 3, the loop would open file descriptors 0,1,2,3. Then you would close the descriptor 3. So it will work in both cases, but the original solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of `fd < 2` is because you have already called the method `int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR, 0);` .

"The file descriptor returned by a  successful call(open) will be the lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process." So if the stdio file descriptors (0/1/2) are missing, the return of `open` has already occupied a missed file descriptors. Then you should judge by 2 rather than 3.